# Cancel Jenkins Post-Build-Task if Selenium-Test (Build-Task) fails

Tags: selenium, jenkins, controls

I'm running a few Selenium-Tests with the SeleniumHQ-Plugin for Jenkins, after the Build-Task with ant. And after the Selenium-Tests, Jenkins is running a Post-Build-Task which deploys the tested Build to a server.

Now, I want to controll this process:

If Selenium-Tests fail Jenkins must not execute the Post-Build-Task, otherwise Jenkins must run the Post-Build-Task.

Is there an option or a plugin or something for Jenkins, which provides the function to listenen to a build-task if it failed and controlls the Post-Build-Task?

Best regards Thomas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create separate jobs and chain them, in which case you can decide whether to run the second job or not based on the success/failure of the current job.  And logically as well, the running of tests and deployment are two different jobs , no?  You can use the Build other projects option or use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: Thanks! Works great with the Parameterized-Tripper-Plugin!